# How to scrape/extract specific Balance Sheet fields from Yahoo Finance from a list of stock tickers?

Tags: python, web-scraping, finance, stock, yahoo-finance

I have a list of tickers in a file named stocktickers.csv (shown below):

| Tickers |
| --- |
| AMD |
| AAPL |
| FB |
| MSFT |
| GOOG |

I would like to scrape Yahoo Finance balance sheet data from that list and input it in the stocktickers.csv file like below.  "Tangible Book Value" and "Shared Issued" are fields found on each ticker's Balance Sheet web page, such as AMD's: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMD/balance-sheet?p=AMD.

| Tickers | Tangible_BV | Shares_Issued |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AMD | 1,000,000 | 500,000 |
| AAPL | 2,000,000 | 200,000 |
| FB | 3,000,000 | 300,000 |
| MSFT | 500,000 | 50,000 |
| GOOG | 4,000,000 | 400,000 |

This is what I have so far, which scrapes the Tangible Book Value for all years.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


header = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36'
}

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/balance-sheet?p=AAPL'

response = requests.get(url, headers=header)

html = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
main = soup.find("div", {"data-reactid": "195"}) #or 196
divs = main.find_all("div")

for div in divs:
    span = div.find("span")
    try:
        print(span.text)
    except:
        pass
```

Result:

```
   Tangible Book Value
Tangible Book Value
65,339,000
90,488,000
107,147,000
126,032,000
```

If there is a way to use `get_balance_sheet()` (from [yfinance module](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/)) to scrape specific balance sheet fields such as those above, that would be great too.

Comment: Why use beautifulsoup instead of the [actual `yfinance` module](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/)?

Comment: Thank you.  Great idea.  I do have that installed and did try it out.  But how to I scrape only specific fields such at 2020 annual Tangible Book Value or Shares Issued from ```get_balance_sheet()``` and insert the values into the .csv file, while using the ticker column to lookup the fields/hyperlinks?  Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure, I've only used the basics of that library for price history. If you [edit] the question to include the output of `get_balance_sheet()`, someone may be able to give a clear answer to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try financialmodelingprep API. You can get that information from a JSON request very easily so you dont have to scrape it.

Comment: Thank you so much for this.  I will check it out and figure out how to use this.  I would still like to scrape from sites like Yahoo though as some OTC and foreign stocks might not have data available on financialmodelingprep API.

Comment: In that case try the Yahoo finance Module, it was made for just that. 
https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/